# Cómo copiar datos en drden SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo las siguientes columnas en la tabla `Items`

```
ItemID Grade
1001   111
1002   569
1003   850
1004   863
```

Tambien tengo tengo las siguientes columnas en la Tabla `Items2`:

```
ItemID Grade
1001   999
1002   999
1003   999
1004   999
```

Necesito pasar el orden `Grade` de la tabla `Items` a la tabla `Items2` para que la tabla `Items2` sea un clon exacto del la otra, es decir, de la tabla `Items`, creo se hacía algo así pero no me funciona:

```
UPDATE PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items
SET Grade = b.Grade
FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items a
INNER JOIN PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items2 b
ON b.Grade = a.Grade
INNER JOIN PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items2 c
ON c.ItemID = a.ItemID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería así:

```
UPDATE b
SET b.Grade = a.Grade
FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items a
INNER JOIN PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items2 b
ON b.ItemID = a.ItemID
```

No sé por qué usas `c`:

```
INNER JOIN PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items2 c
ON c.ItemID = a.ItemID
```